# using URLS in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am trying to parse about 6000 urls from a text file line by line and return their http status code. I have it working for the most part but when my script encounters semi-colons and other various symbols it breaks the script. I am wondering if there is a way to make sure it escapes these characters and still allows cURL to run properly?

This is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    name=$line
    test="curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w "%{http_code}" $name"
    eval "$test"
done < $1
```

This is an example of an error:

```
./checkURL.sh: eval: line 6: `curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w %{http_code} http://xtblast.com/ptv/?attachment_id=855&repl&replytoco;&replytocom=32954'
./checkURL.sh: eval: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `;&'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many quotes. Try a single quote instead:

```
test="curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w %{http_code} '$name'"
```

To adept the comments, it should be sufficient to use the script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    /usr/bin/curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w %{http_code} -- "$line"
done < $1
```

Comment: It's best to avoid [putting commands in strings](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). If you want to be able to both print and execute a command, an array is better.

Comment: There's also, in this case, literally no reason to need the variable and `exec`.

Comment: You must using doublequotes , `"$line"` instead of `'$line'`. Try to add ` -- ` before `$line`, so value of `$line` was considered as argument not an option. `/usr/bin/curl -s -o /dev/null -I -w %{http_code} -- "$line"`